# Need to create an SPC chart that updates with new data and uses the last 30 cells as range

Tags: excel, vba, graph, range, spc

I need some help with Writing some VBA code that produces a line chart. The chart needs to update when new data is added and I also need the displayed range of data to be the last 30 cells of data. I am having to add this to an existing workbook and have been able to write VBA that displays the already existing data on a chart.

what I have already created

```
Sub Chartspc()
Dim chrt As ChartObject

Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim r3 As Range
Dim r4 As Range

 Set r1 = Sheets("Breather L551").Range("J231:J261")
 Set r2 = Sheets("Breather L551").Range("N231:N261")
 Set r3 = Sheets("Breather L551").Range("R231:R261")
 Set r4 = Sheets("Breather L551").Range("V231:V261")


Set chrt = Sheets("GRAPHTEST").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=0, Width:=600, Top:=0, Height:=300)
chrt.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Union(r1, r2, r3, r4)
With chrt
.Chart.ChartType = xlLine
.Chart.HasTitle = True
.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "L551"
.Chart.SetElement (msoElementLegendRight)
.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "LrA CP"
.Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "LrB CP"
.Chart.SeriesCollection(3).Name = "LrC CP"
.Chart.SeriesCollection(4).Name = "LrD CP"
End With
End Sub
```

In More detail I want to be able to create a graph from the bottom 30 cells of data I have. I then want new data to be represented on the graph and old data that is outside my 30 cell range removed or not represented on the graph; this would be bottom cell and the 29 cells above it and then everything adjusts down one cell when new data is added.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. You should [share code, not images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please, edit your question, delete the link to the pictures and copy your code(s) as they are.

Comment: Both of us told you that you do not have to show us pictures! If somebody wants helping you, he should simple copy your (editable) code...

Comment: You try creating a chart having a single cell as source ("J31"). Is this what you want? If not copying the editable code, at least, try  explaining **in works** what you try accomplishing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It will create a chart with series ranges containing the last 30 rows (calculated based on J:J column last row):

```
Sub Chartspc()
 Dim wsB As Worksheet, wsG As Worksheet, lastR As Long, firstR As Long
 Dim chrt As ChartObject, r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range, r4 As Range

 Set wsB = Sheets("Breather L551")
 Set wsG = Sheets("GRAPHTEST")
 lastR = wsB.Range("J" & wsB.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'J
 If lastR > 31 Then
    firstR = lastR - 29
 Else
   firstR = 2
 End If
 Set r1 = wsB.Range("J" & firstR & ":" & "J" & lastR)
 Set r2 = wsB.Range("N" & firstR & ":" & "N" & lastR)
 Set r3 = wsB.Range("R" & firstR & ":" & "R" & lastR)
 Set r4 = wsB.Range("V" & firstR & ":" & "V" & lastR)

 On Error Resume Next
   wsG.ChartObjects("Chart30Rows").Delete 'delete the chart if it exists
 On Error GoTo 0
 
 Set chrt = wsG.ChartObjects.Add(left:=0, width:=600, top:=0, height:=300)
 chrt.Name = "Chart30Rows"
 chrt.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Union(r1, r2, r3, r4)
 With chrt
    .Chart.ChartType = xlLine
    .Chart.HasTitle = True
    .Chart.chartTitle.Text = "L551"
    .Chart.SetElement (msoElementLegendRight)
    .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "LrA CP"
    .Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "LrB CP"
    .Chart.SeriesCollection(3).Name = "LrC CP"
    .Chart.SeriesCollection(4).Name = "LrD CP"
 End With
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback. I could not test it...

The code can be adapted to search if the chart already exist and create a new one, if not, or only feed the `SeriesCollection` with the new ranges, if existing. But not having similar data to test it, it is a little more complicated.

Comment: @MarcDlee Didn't you find some time to test the above code, written for you? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: Sorry I was busy over the weekend, this code doesn't produce a chart object at all for me I'm going to try and test it and get it work.

Comment: @MarcDlee You should use your **real** sheets name instead the ones I used to try testing the code (the commented part)... Now, I updated it with your sheets name. Please test it now, or only try using your sheets  name.

Comment: sorry that was a Dumb mistake for me to make it works thankyou very much.

Comment: @MarcDlee No problem... Glad I could help!